# My dropdown menu is working but it goes down under the Navbar

Tags: html, css, frontend

My Dropdown menu opens up but it goes down under behind the screen like unless I increase the navbar height it isn't visible.
here is my code.
I want it to come on top of everything so the user can actually see it.
It goes underneath the nav section, so is not visible.

```css
.sub-menu {
  display: none;
  margin-top: 0 !important;
}

.navbar-header .navbar-ul .main-menu-items .about-us-menu #about-sub-menu {
  z-index: 100;
  position: relative;
}

.navbar-header .navbar-ul .about-us-menu .sub-menu {
  width: 150px;
}

.navbar-header .navbar-ul .about-us-menu .sub-menu ul li a {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.sub-menu ul li {
  margin: 15px;
  width: 120px;
  position: relative;
  /* padding: 15px; */
}

.navbar-header .navbar-ul .courses-sub-menu:hover .sub-menu ul li a {
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.navbar-header .navbar-ul .about-us-menu .sub-menu {
  width: 180px;
}

.navbar-header ul li:hover .sub-menu {
  display: block !important;
  position: absolute;
  background: #333333;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.sub-menu ul:hover {
  display: block !important;
}

.navbar-header ul li:hover .sub-menu ul {
  display: block;
  /* margin: 10px;  */
}

.sub-menu ul li:hover {
  display: block;
  background: #f5f5f7;
  color: black !important;
}

.sub-menu ul li a {
  color: #f5f5f7;
}

.navbar-header ul li:hover .sub-menu ul li {
  display: block !important;
  color: black;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 0 !important;
  border-radius: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.sub-menu ul li a:hover {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar-header" style="padding: 0; margin: 0; ">
  <ul class="navbar-ul">
    <div class="main-menu-items">
      <li>
        <a routerLink="/home"><img src="../../../assets/xyz" class="navbar-logo" alt=""></a>
      </li>
      <!-- logo -->
      <!-- <li><a routerLink="/home">Home</a></li> -->
      <!-- <li><a routerLink="/aboutus">About Us</a></li> -->
      <li class="about-us-menu"><a routerLink="#">About Us</a>
        <div class="sub-menu">
          <ul id="about-sub-menu">
            <li>
              <a href="/aboutus/gallery">Gallery</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="/testimonials">Testimonials</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="/blog">Blogs</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="courses-sub-menu"><a routerLink="/courses">Courses</a>
        <div class="sub-menu">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Science</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Physics</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Biology</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Mathematics</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Chemistry</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Business Studies</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Accountancy</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Economics</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Psychology</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">SAT/ACT</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
```

Comment: I actually do not understand where the problem is and how to reproduce it. Moreover I neither see "navbar height" nor "nav section" you talking about. What is your target? An "always-on-top-menu" on the left side with a scrollable content on the right?

Comment: @ent3 Hey thanx for the response, so basically what is happening is that when I hover on the navitem about us then ideally there should be a drop down but nothing was happening so i tried to increase the navbar height and noticed that it's working just that it's happening underneath the navbar, also this was perfectly working as it was intended to but now for some reason this is happeneing.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3hb2zkjd/5/ take a look at this fiddle, maybe this gonna help you. I simplified a bit your html/css. I'd recommend you not to define classes several times your code.. I also removed the div's which were wrapping your lists and just added the classes on the lists themselves. I dont know if the fiddle solves your issue, but maybe you can at least get an advantage/idea of it.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.
Check out these CSS properties to achieve your desired result.

```
.main-menu-items {
  background: none;
  color: Black;
  padding: 12px 26px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}


.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 160px;
}

.sub-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.sub-menu a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.sub-menu a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .sub-menu {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

.nav-wrapper {
  display: block;
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="main-menu-items">About Us</button>
        <div class="sub-menu">
          <a href="#">Gallery</a>
          <a href="#">Testimonials</a>
          <a href="#">Blogs</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="main-menu-items">Courses</button>
        <div class="sub-menu">
          <a href="#">Science</a>
          <a href="#">Physics</a>
          <a href="#">Biology</a>
          <a href="#">Mathematics</a>
          <a href="#">Chemistry</a>
          <a href="#">Business Studies</a>
          <a href="#">Accountancy</a>
          <a href="#">Economics</a>
          <a href="#">Psychology</a>
          <a href="#">SAT/ACT</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>    
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```